# Spectral Graph Theory :Cartesian product of Laplace Matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

Let $G\times H$ be the Cartesian Product of $G$ and $H$.

> > Determine $L(G\times H)$ in terms of $L(G)$ and $L(H)$ where $L(G) $ denotes Laplacian Matrix of $G$.
> >
> > Also find the eigen values of $L(G\times H)$ in terms of $L(G)$ and $L(H)$.

**My try**:

Let $|V(G)|=n;|V(H)|=m$ .Then $|V(G\times H)|=m\times n$.

Now two vertices $(v,w)\sim (v_1,w_1)\iff v\sim v_1 \text{and} w\sim w_1$.

I am unable to understand how the $(i,j)^{th}$ entry of $L(G\times H)$ will look.

Please give some hints. I am unable to solve the problem.

Comment: Follow the paper -  Barik, S., Bapat, R.B. and Pati, S., 2015. On the Laplacian spectra of product graphs. Applicable Analysis and Discrete Mathematics, 9(1), pp.39-58.

Comment: @G_0_pi_i_e; I have just started reading spectral graph theory from the book "Graphs and Matrices" Laplacian Matrices ; it would have been better if you could give some hints on solving the problem

Comment: I don't have any experience on how to read papers

Comment: Anyway ;I found you are doing research in Spectral in IIT ;can you please give some books apart from Bapat which I can use /you are using as a beginner;

Comment: Books: 1. Algebraic Graph Theory by Godsil, Royle.  2. Spectra of graphs by Cvetkovic, Doob, Sachs.   3.   Spectra of graphs by Brouwers and Haemers.

Comment: For the problem:
 Do you know Kronecker product of matrices? If not first have some idea about it and some of its properties. Then by considering one example you can be sure that $$L(G\times H)=L(G)\otimes I_n+I_m\otimes L(F),$$ where $\otimes$ stands for Kronecker product operation. Then the further result becomes immediate.

Comment: I am extremely grateful for your comments

Comment: But I am unable to do the proof of the given result ;though I have used an example ;I am unable to prove it formally

Comment: Will you please help;

Comment: Do you get its matrix representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important properties of Kronecker product operation:   $$(A\otimes B)(C\otimes D)=AC\otimes BD,$$ $$A\otimes(B+C)=A\otimes B+A\otimes C.$$ Now if $L(G)X_i=\lambda_i X_i$ and $L(F)Y_j=\mu_j Y_j$, then \begin{align*}L(G\times H)(X_i\otimes Y_j)&=(L(G)\otimes I_m+I_n\otimes L(H))(X_i\otimes Y_j)\\&=L(G)X_i\otimes I_mY_j+I_nX_i\otimes L(H)Y_j\\&=\lambda_iX_i\otimes Y_j+\mu_jX_i\otimes Y_j\\&=(\lambda_i+\mu_j)X_i\otimes Y_j.\end{align*}

Comment: I have got all the steps ;my trouble is I am not getting why $L(G\times H)=L(G)\times I_m+I_n\times L(H)$

Comment: It's not $L(G)\times I_m$, rather $L(G)\otimes I_m$.
That is why I am telling you go through Kronecker product. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

Comment: Take one example and write down the name of the vertices as $(v_G, v_H)$. Consider them in lexicographic order and try to form $A(G\times H)$, the adjacency matrix. I am sure you can get your result.